# Select and wrap specific parent elements with siblings until next specific parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, parent

I am looking to use jQuery to select the `p` tags which are the grandparent element of a span with a certain class `hdr`, I then want to wrap that p tag and all of it's siblings up until the next p tag which is a parent of a `hdr` class, so on and so forth.

The problem I have is that the 2nd and 3rd wrappers and it's containing content end up getting nested inside of their previous set of wrappers instead of each wrapper being printed one after another.

My Initial Markup:

```js
$('.main .hdr').parents('p').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil($(this)).addBack().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <p><strong><span class="hdr">Heading #1</span></strong></p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>

  <p><strong><span class="hdr">Heading #2</span></strong></p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>

  <p><strong><span class="hdr">Heading #3</span></strong></p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>

</div>
```

Current Output:

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p><strong><span class="hdr">Heading #1</span></strong></p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p><strong><span class="hdr">Heading #2</span></strong></p>
      <p>Some paragraph text</p>
      <p>Some paragraph text</p>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p><strong><span class="hdr">Heading #3</span></strong></p>
        <p>Some paragraph text</p>
        <p>Some paragraph text</p>
        <p>Some paragraph text</p>
        <p>Some paragraph text</p>
        <p>Some paragraph text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Desired Output:

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p><strong><span class="hdr">Heading #1</span></strong></p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p><strong><span class="hdr">Heading #2</span></strong></p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p><strong><span class="hdr">Heading #3</span></strong></p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqn9kohu/7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, passing in the selection to `nextUntil`, or even just `p:has(.hdr)` would work, instead of `$(this)`

```
var elems = $('.main p:has(.hdr)');

elems.each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(elems).addBack().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pqn9kohu/9/)